# Question about transferring GTA 5 account (xbox 360 to PS4) regarding xbox live/PSN

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-network, psn, grand-theft-auto-online

So, I have followed most of the steps that I can [located here](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-or-Xbox-One), however I do not have a physical copy of GTA 5 for PS4 just yet (I intend to get it eventually).  I used to play on xbox 360, but now have PS4.  I have a PSN ID, but have not paid for the online service (I don't have Playstation Plus).  I have linked my rockstar account online to my PSN ID.

My question is this, can I cancel my Xbox live account and still transfer my online progress to PS4?  My renewal is coming up for Xbox live and I would like to cancel it before paying for another whole year if I can help it.  Does anyone have experience with this?  **Has anyone transferred their online account (Rockstar account) from Xbox 360 to Playstation 4 but cancelled their Xbox live account before doing so?**  I didn't specifically see anything in the instructions about it, but I did not want to assume.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out cancelling before transferring worked just fine!!!